# JList content not updated

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a jList object named jListCustSearchResults which holds a number of CustomerEntity objects and shows them as a list for a user to to select a customer.

The first method below is an actionperformed mthod of a JButton which triggers the update sequence of this JList when clicked. It invokes another function below named fillCustomerList to refill the JList object with the new Customers retrieved from the database.

The problem here is that so mentioned jList object is not updated in the gui. Instead it's completely empty. As an alternative solution, I placed the method refillCustomerList into a SwingWorker object within its doBackground method  in order that the update does not happen in EDT. However, the jLIst is still not updated with the new content on the GUI. Why do you think it's not updated?

At the bottom of this message I placed the SwingWorker variant of my implementation. The jList is still not updated in the gui (I also invoked repaint()).

```
private void jTextFieldCustomerSearchWordActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                                             
    int filterType = jComboBoxSearchType.getSelectedIndex() + 1;
    String filterWord = jTextFieldCustomerSearchWord.getText();

    try {
        controller.repopulateCustomerListByFilterCriteria(filterType, filterWord);
    } catch (ApplicationException ex) {
        Helper.processExceptionLog(ex, true);
    }

    refillCustomerList();
}                                                            

private void refillCustomerList() {
    if (jListCustSearchResults.getModel().getSize() != 0) {
        jListCustSearchResults.removeAll();
    }

    jListCustSearchResults.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
        List<CustomerEntity> customerList = controller.getCustomerList();

        @Override
        public int getSize() {
            return customerList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getElementAt(int i) {
            return customerList.get(i);
        }
    });

    jListCustSearchResults.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
```

==========================

## WITH SWING WORKER variant:

```
private void jTextFieldCustomerSearchWordActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)   {

    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        public void done() {
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            int filterType = jComboBoxSearchType.getSelectedIndex() + 1;
            String filterWord = jTextFieldCustomerSearchWord.getText();

            try {
                controller.repopulateCustomerListByFilterCriteria(filterType, filterWord);
            } catch (ApplicationException ex) {
                Helper.processExceptionLog(ex, true);
            }

            refillCustomerList();
            return null;
           }
    };

    worker.execute();
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell from your code. Please post an sscce: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: I tried explain the problem in a more stepwise way. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: not looking into your problem, but: your swingWorker implementation is completely _wrong_ - doInBackground _must not_ access swing components nor their properties.

Comment: ok this swing worker perhaps was a blind trial but how about the original code? Do you have a comment on that?

Comment: Ok, it the problem was about the toString method of my Customer instances. The content was being added but it was not printing null.

Comment: Awesome! However, how did you expect anyone to guess that with the pieces of code you have posted?